# Fixing function from swift 1.0 to 1.2

Tags: swift, syntax

I just upgraded to the new swift and can't figure out how to fix this function. Any ideas? I get the error below and my first and return lines:

> '(@Ivalue String!) -> _' is not identical to 'NSInteger'

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        var countx = count(textView.text) + (count(text) - count(range))
        var t = String(countx) + "/500"
        countText.text = t
        return count(textView.text) + (count(text) - count(range)) <= 500
    }
```

Comment: What is your stack trace when the error happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ->

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let countx = count(textView.text) + (count(text) - range.length)
        countText.text = "\(countx)/500"
        return countx <= 500
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Swift 1.0 to Swift 1.2
First you select a target and then it’s very similar to how refactoring works – Xcode will churn away and then come back with a preview. You’ll see the old code and new code side-by-side with the changes highlighted.

Go Edit\Convert\To Swift 1.2

I hope its work....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, was very helpful. Turns out I had a variable named `count`. Since the function was `countElements` before there was no conflict.